# Unable to fetch data from Firebird 1.5 MATLAB

Tags: matlab, firebird, jaybird

I have setup a connection to a remote Firebird 1.5 Server (WIN7) through MATLAB RR2015b (MAC Yosemite) and I am able to access it freely through the Database Explorer in MATLAB. However, I am facing some issues when I try to do the same through a .m script.

My code looks like this:

```
cstr='jdbc:firebirdsql:192.168.2.143:c:\DB\test.GDB';
conn = database('','sysdba','masterkey','org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver',cstr);
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','numeric');
material_codes='SELECT MAT_ID, MAT_PLUCODE FROM MATERIALS';
material_codes = fetch(conn,material_codes);
close(conn);
```

After running the script, all I receive is a new empty matrix with no date inside. If I try to do the same through the GUI (Database Explorer) I am able to export without issues. If anyone is able to throw some light on this issue, I would really appreciate it.